# NTFS RAID partition plus Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows-7, raid

Periodically I find one of my old photos or other files has become 0Kb and lost.   By the time I have found this the backup is the same. So I am considering using RAID 5 or perhaps RAID 1 to protection one NTFS partition.  I have no prior experience with RAID software or hardware and would like some help getting started?

I can fit up to 4 HDDs and I use the larger HDs to have bootable Linux Debian or Lubuntu Window 7 or Windows 10 say. But I want to be sure that all operating systems will work with out one corrupting data but from what I read this may be difficult? Or I just don't understand if this is possible and a reasonable strategy?

I am planning to use an old Fujitsu server as my desktop with an old sound card.  I mention that because the server can handle RAID 0 or 1 I do not have setup software for it and I do not expect it to be clever enough to just handle use of part of a HDD? So I have in mind to use software RAID.

The BIOS handles simple 3 primary +1 extended partitions. Would putting the raid partition first then the window boot partition then one Linux the windows and Linux-swap as extended partitions. There for each HDD would be bootable with grub and Linux but only some would also have Windows.

I also intend to use two of the SATA cables for rescuing and copying hard disks such as for my laptop occasionally.  RAID must not interfere with doing that.

Comment: RAID is not backup.

Comment: So are you saying it will not save files becoming 0Kb due to ordinary way storage works around losing clusters.  I am not otherwise planning to use RAID to backup I back up everything to one of a number of USB sticks once a month anyway but that is only to recover things that I have deleted or edited unintentionally or a computer failure.

Comment: If you already have backups then fine, that's what I was hinting of, nothing else. Now I must complement it with RAID isn't a solution for failing drives or any other condition causing file corruption.

Comment: I will wait to see what other people say.  

I used two dimensional parity checking to protect a 256 byte serial EEPROM,  that is as big as you could get 30 years ago.  If the instrument was turned off during a save this software would recover at least one byte and warn if two bytes were lost.  It used 32 bytes.  This was what I was hoping for but on a bigger scale.

I am not talking about using HDDs that are in a poor state but using HDDs that are good or excellent but of cause will in the normal way of running loose data and replace clusters as a part of SMART.

Answer (score 0):

I have abandoned that idea of using RAID.   That is I just have three HDDs in this server which I use as a desktop.  Therefore I simply zip up directories to one or of the 2nd or third disk and a USB sticks for backing up.

The problem therefore is I can not discover files that have become corrupted lost and are 0 bytes.  I loose any good version of those broken files when I delete the oldest back up.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).